# Android 8.0 Oreo InputType numberPassword not working - visible

Tags: java, android, xml, android-8.0-oreo

I've got some issue which is kind of weird.

There's an `EditText` with `android:inputType="numberPassword"` but I can input also numbers and characters. Also whole text is visible and **not** marked by "•••".

Does anyone have the same issue?
It was reported by user in Google Play Store and it also occurs in Android 8.0.0 emulator system. It **doesn't occur** on my OnePlus 5T also with Oreo 8.0.0 (OxygenOS 5.0.3).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:inputType="numberPassword"
```

OR

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Both will working fine.

May be you have older version of some components, make sure you have newer ones.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="273dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.507"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.667"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/idGetPsw"
            android:layout_width="301dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColorLink="#FF3649AE"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.507"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/idGetEmail"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.052"
            tools:ignore="NotSibling" />


    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: its's just simple `EditText`, not with `TextInputLayout`. I need it to be numeric (not decimal) and password. Changing it temporarily to `textPassword` doesnt't change anything. I've got four EditTexts for four pin digits.
What do you mean by "some components"? I've got support version "27.0.2"

Comment: There is no difference between simple `edittext` and `TextInputLayout edittext`,
`TextInputLayout` is for floating animation inside it there is a simple `edittext` only. i have tried with simple `edittext` both `numberPassword` & `textPassword` works.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is changing device security setting "show password" to OFF and now it's okay.